# How to check in Groovy that object is a list or collection or array?

Tags: collections, groovy

The question is as simple as the title. How to check in Groovy that object is a list or collection or array? But can't find a simple way of checking it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't know if you need to distinguish between Collection, List and Array, or just want to know if an object is *any* of these types. If the latter, you could use this:

```
boolean isCollectionOrArray(object) {    
    [Collection, Object[]].any { it.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass()) }
}

// some tests
assert isCollectionOrArray([])
assert isCollectionOrArray([] as Set)
assert isCollectionOrArray([].toArray())
assert !isCollectionOrArray("str")
```

Run the code above in the Groovy console to confirm it behaves as advertised

Answer (score 45):

A `List` is a `Collection`, so the checks aren't mutually exclusive:

```
def foo = ...
boolean isCollection = foo instanceof Collection
boolean isList = foo instanceof List
boolean isSet = foo instanceof Set
boolean isArray = foo != null && foo.getClass().isArray()
```

Comment: That's the same way I can do it in Java :). So, no Groovy way?

Comment: "boolean isArray = foo instanceof Object[]" should work too.  If foo is null it will return false and not throw an Exception.

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel. IMHO the Java syntax is pretty concise in this case, and a lot more readable than the suggested groovy-way solution.

Comment: I agree with peterp... but I find it curious that Groovy doesn't supply a simple way to run such a test (unless it now 2018-02-14 does, of course ...)

Comment: FWIW this works perfectly with Hashes too: Swap the two map defs around and see: 
```
def map = [me: 'you', him: 'her']
// def map = 'just a string'


if (map instanceof HashMap) {
  println 'hash'
}
else {
  println 'not hash'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a Groovy way, look at `in` operator. It is actually a combination of `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` and `Class.isInstance(Object)` meaning that you can use it to test classes as well as objects.

```
// Test classes
assert ArrayList in Collection
assert ArrayList in List
assert HashSet in Collection
assert HashSet in Set

// Test objects
def list = [] as ArrayList
def set = [] as HashSet

assert list in Collection
assert list in List
assert set in Collection
assert set in Set
```

Testing if an object is an array may be tricky. I would recommend @BurtBeckwith's approach.

```
def array = [].toArray()

assert array.getClass().isArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this to "arrayfy" an object, if its already a collection then it will return a copy, else wrap it in a list. So you don't need to check it while processing, it will be always a collection.

```
def arrayfy = {[] + it ?: [it]}
def list = arrayfy(object) // will be always a list
```

Comment: I got an error unless I capitalized the 'O' in object

Comment: `object` here is just the name of a variable, can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd want to check its behavior with [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

```
def foo = someMethod()
if (foo.metaClass.respondsTo('each')) {
  foo.each {println it}
}
```

Comment: String respondsTo each as well, I think

Comment: Groovy adds the `each` method to `Object` so every object responds to `each`. Therefore, this proposal is faulty.

Comment: Yikes, I didn't realize `Object` responded to `each`. Either way, you'd want to check the method you're actually going to use, so if you're using a different method this might work ok. If you do plan to use `each` then unfortunately this won't be sufficient.

Comment: why not just use the object's class to determine it's type instead of checking for the presence of a particular method? I don't see any benefit to using this approach over `instanceof`?

Comment: The benefit of duck typing is that you're not hard-coding a particular implementation. A caller can use your documentation to decide what to pass if they prefer a different implementation (or their own, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the instanceof operator and check if the object is an instance of java.util.Collection

Comment: Burt answered that, there's no groovy way..but i'd also try object instanceof Object[]...but absolutely not sure about it