# Jenkins - configure gradle installation using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure gradle using init.groovy with the following code:

```
def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
def gradle_inst_exists = false
def gradle4 = new hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation("grade4", "/usr/share/gradle", [])
def gradleInstallationDescriptor = instance.getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation.DescriptorImpl)
def installations = gradleInstallationDescriptor.getInstallations()
println(installations.size())
installations.each {
  installation = (hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation) it
  if (gradle4.getName() == installation.getName()) {
    gradle_inst_exists = true
    println("found installation")
  }
}
if (!gradle_inst_exists) {
  installations.add(gradle4)
  gradleInstallationDescriptor.setInstallations(installations)
  gradleInstallationDescriptor.save()
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Lhudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation;.add() is applicable for argument types: (hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation) values: [GradleInstallation[grade4]]
Possible solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), min(), last(), sum()
```

Been beating my head against the wall trying to fix the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got a Jenkins to hand to confirm, but from here it looks like you're trying to `add` to an `Array` not a `List`.

Looking at what seems to be the source for [getInstallations](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/gradle/GradleInstallation.java#L119), it returns a `GradleInstallation[]` rather than `List<GradleInstallation>` as perhaps you're assuming.

Groovy's `each()` supports Arrays, helpfully (usually):

```
groovy> [1,2,3].toArray().each { print "Got $it." }
Got 1.Got 2.Got 3
```

So when you try to *modify* the array, you'll need to do this with arrays, which is usually horrible. Easiest is probably convert to a list (with `toList`:

```
def installations = gradleInstallationDescriptor.getInstallations().toList()
```

then add your new item as before (or use `<<` if you prefer), then convert back to an array before calling the setter:

```
gradleInstallationDescriptor.setInstallations((GradleInstall‌​ation[])  installations)
```

Some good background in [Groovy- Difference between List, ArrayList and Object Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483640/groovy-difference-between-list-arraylist-and-object-array)

Hope that helps

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but now the script errors on the `setInstallations`.
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation$DescriptorImpl.setInstallations() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Object;) values: [[GradleInstallation[grade4]]]
Possible solutions: setInstallations([Lhudson.tools.ToolInstallation;), setInstallations([Lhudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation;), getInstallations(), getInstallations()`

Comment: I guess you'll need to cast it to a `GradleInstallation[]`, or alternatively define the list explicitly as a `List<GradleInstallation>`

Comment: Solved! Changed `def installations = gradleInstallationDescriptor.getInstallations().toList()` and added cast `  gradleInstallationDescriptor.setInstallations((GradleInstallation[]) installations)`
Can you fix your response so I can mark it answered?

Comment: And one doesn't need the `toArray()`