# Feeding parameters to Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a Jenkins shared library that I use for my Jenkinsfile. My library has an entire pipeline and it has a function (lets call it `examFun()`) that is used within my pipeline.

My Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('some-shared-lib') _

jenkinsPipeline{
    exampleArg = "yes"
}
```

My shared library file (called *jenkinsPipeline.groovy*):

```
def examFun(){
  return [
     new randClass(name: 'Creative name no 1', place: 'London')
     new randClass(name: 'Creating name no 2', place: 'Berlin')
  ]
}

def call(body) {
    def params= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()

    pipeline {
        // My entire pipeline is here
        // Demo stage
        stage("Something"){
          steps{
            script{
              projectName = params.exampleArg
            }
          }
        }

    }
}

class randClass {
    String name
    String place
}
```

It is working fine, but the values of `examFun()` are hardcoded and may need to be changed in the future. As such, I would like to be able to change them from my Jenkinsfile (just like I can change  `exampleArg`). Following [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) article, I tried the following:

I changed my `examFun()` to

```
def examFun(String[] val){
  return [
     new randClass(name: val[0], place: 'London')
     new randClass(name: val[1], place: 'Berlin')
  ]
}
```

And call it from my Jenkinsfile as follows

```
@Library('some-shared-lib') _

jenkinsPipeline.examFun(['Name 1','Name 2'])
jenkinsPipeline{
    exampleArg = "yes"
}
```

But that did not work (probably because my library is structured via  `def call(body){}`). After, I tried to split jenkinsPipeline.groovy into 2 files: first file having my pipeline part, and second file having `examFun()` with `randClass` in it. I modified my Jenkinsfile to be as follows:

```
@Library('some-shared-lib') _
def config = new projectConfig() // New groovy filed is called 'projectConfig.groovy'
config.examFun(["Name 1","Name 2"])

jenkinsPipeline{
    exampleArg = "yes"
}
```

But again did not succeed. The error always says

```
No such DSL method 'examFun()' found among steps
```

**Update - New error**

Thanks to zett42 , I have successfully resolved this error. However, I run into another error mentioned below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
```

To solve it, in my case, I needed to assign `examFun()` to a variable in my Jenkinsfile and pass it as a parameter in `jenkinsPipeline{}`. The functioning code is as follows:
*Jenkinsfile*:

```
@Library('some-shared-lib') _

def list = jenkinsPipeline.examFun(['Name 1','Name 2'])
def names = jenkinsPipeline.someFoo(list)
jenkinsPipeline{
    exampleArg = "yes"
    choiceArg = names
}
```

*jenkinsPipeline.groovy*:

```
def examFun(List<String> val){
  return [
     new randClass(name: val[0], place: 'London')
     new randClass(name: val[1], place: 'Berlin')
  ]
}
def call(body) {
    def params= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()

    pipeline {
        // My entire pipeline is here
        parameters{
          choice(name: "Some name", choices: params.choiceArg, description:"Something")
        }
        // Demo stage
        stage("Something"){
          steps{
            script{
              projectName = params.exampleArg
            }
          }
        }

    }
}

def someFoo(list) {
    def result = []
    list.each{
        result.add(it.name)
    }
    return result
}

class randClass {
    String name
    String place
}
```

Comment: I also encountered various issue trying to instantiate code between the script world and the classpath of this sharedLibrary context. I believe this is related to the same fundamental issue of finding the code of  the groovy scripts in the classpath world so it works like real code and not just some hacking......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an error "no such DSL method..." it often just means that the types of parameters and actually passed arguments are incompatible, which is the case here.

The function `examFun()` expects an array, but you are actually passing an `ArrayList`. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484253/7571258), low level arrays are not really idiomatic in Groovy.

Try this instead:

```
def examFun(List<String> val){
  return [
     new randClass(name: val[0], place: 'London')
     new randClass(name: val[1], place: 'Berlin')
  ]
}
```

`List` is the more general interface, which `ArrayList` implements.

Now, your first jenkinsfile example should work:

```
jenkinsPipeline.examFun(['Name 1','Name 2'])
```

You actually can have additional named methods, even when you already have a `call` method. I'm using this all the time.

Comment: That indeed solves my error. However, I do get ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object``` error now. The error seems to be coming from a part of a script that needs ```examFun()``` to work. I left everything in one groovy file.

Comment: I think it happens because ```examFun()``` is called twice: first via  ```jenkinsPipeline.examFun(['Name 1','Name 2'])``` and then by ```jenkinsPipeline{}``` (which possibly overwrites it?Not sure if this is true).

Comment: @Joe Please edit your question to add your current code at the bottom (please keep original question intact so we have the "history").

Comment: Added my current code, as well as a link that I tried to use to solve my current problem.

Comment: I figured it out - I needed to store ```jenkinsPipeline.examFun(['Name 1','Name 2'])``` as some variable and pass this variable as a parameter in ```jenkinsPipeline{}```. I will edit this in my answer but will accept yours as a final answer since it dealt with original problem.